# применение свойств класса внутри функции

Tags: javascript, html

В `<body>` есть элемент 
`<p><input id="btn" name="btn" type="submit" value="Click"></p>` 
и 
`<ol id="list"></ol>`. 
При нажатии кнопки должен создаваться список, обрабатывается функцией:

```
$('#btn').click(function(e){
  $('<div id="divM1"/>').appendTo($( "#list" ));
  $('<span />').addClass('expandEditor ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n').appendTo($( "#divM1" ));
  $('<span id="span1"/>').appendTo($( "#divM1" ));
  $('<span id="span2"/>').addClass('itemTitle').appendTo($( "#span1" ));
  $('<input type="text" value="Name menu"/>').addClass('textDiv').appendTo($( "#span2" ));
  $('<div id="divM2"/>').addClass('menuEdit hidden').appendTo($( "#divM1" ));
  $('<p id="par"/>').appendTo($( "#divM2" ));
  $('<input type="text" value="MyText"/>').addClass('text').appendTo($( "#par" ));
});
```

В третьей строке к span должен применятся класс 'expandEditor'. Но он не работает.

JS:

```
$('.expandEditor').attr('title','Click to show/hide item editor');

$('.expandEditor, .itemTitle').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $('#menuEdit'+id).toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-n').toggleClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-s');
});
```

Каким способом можно применить свойства класса для тега? Может есть более удобный способ добавления элементов на страницу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому в общем случае и рекомендуют писать

```
$(document).on('click', '.class', function(){ ... });
```

Вместо

```
$('.class').on('click', function(){ ... });
```

Первое будет работать в любом случае, когда бы не добавили элемент на страницу.

А второе привязывает событие только к тем элементам .class, которые уже оказались на странице после загрузки.

P.s. `attr('data-id')` == `data('id');`

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, заменить 
$('.expandEditor, .itemTitle').click(function(){...});
на 
$(document).on('click', '.expandEditor, .itemTitle', function(){ ...});

Если так, то  
var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
в этой строке не находится id

В обработчике кнопки передаю этот параметр:  
$('<div id="menuEdit555"/>').addClass('menuEdit hidden').appendTo($( "#divM1" ));

Comment: @Alin `var id = this.id;`

Comment: в таком случае id не определен. в консоли выводится undefined

Comment: Потому что перепутали id и data-id )
Если в HTML имеем `<div id="bubu" data-id="moo"></div>`
В таком случае `this.id` будет равен `bubu;` а `this.dataset.id = moo;`
Аналог на jQ: `$(this).attr('id')` - это bubu, а `$(this).data('id')` будет moo (всё написанное предполагает, что была привязана какая-то функция к div, чтобы при запуске функции, this выделял сам div)

Comment: Действительно, у меня все было напутано с id. Пересмотрев эти параметры, все получилось. Спасибо вам.